# comparing two strings with Turing Machine

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language, turing-machines

Reading about Multitape Turing Machines and coming across this exercise: Construct a Turing Machine, that can "tell" if a word w1 on strip 1 matches w2 on strip 2.
Given approach : Compare the states on the strips.

Okay, who would have thought^^?!

But how can I  build such an If-case in a Turing?

Answer (score 2):

The two-tape machine has a transition function $\delta$ which takes the current state, $s$, and the symbols from the current positions on the two tapes, $t_1$ and $t_2$, and tells what the new state $s'$ is.

Define a transition function that gives $\delta(s, t_1, t_2)$ one value when $t_1=t_2$, and a different value when $t_1\ne t_2$.  Then the machine will go into different states depending on whether $t_1=t_2$ and can proceed differently from there.